# convert a graph represented by a string of key-value pairs, to a dictionary. Python

Tags: python

given a map, represented by a string of double digit numbers separated by commas e.g "12,23,34,45,56,67,78,81" where each pair of digits represents a path between the two digits, convert the string into a graph represented by a dictionary with keys as origins(digits) and values as available destinations from key. e.g 1:[2,8], 2[3] etc.
This is my very ugly attempt:

```
def path(way):
x = way.split(',')
y = sorted(set(tele.replace(',','')))
graph = dict()
for i in x:
    for j in range(len(i)):
        for h in y:
            if h in i and i[j] != h:
                if h in graph:
                    graph[h].append((i[j]))
                else:
                    graph[h] = [(i[j])]
return graph
```

I intend on implementing the Breadth-first search algorithm after this in order to find the best path. I'm sorry if my explanation is unclear. Any help would be very appreciated, thanks!

Comment: what does `1:[2,8]` mean? is it an undirected graph?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the unclear explanation. It means that from point 1, you can either move to point 8 or point 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# this initializes values in the dictionary d with empty lists
# so that we can directly call .append() without checking "if key in keys"
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)

# your input string
s = "12,23,34,45,56,67,78,81"

# iterate through digit pairs
for pair in s.split(","):
  # get single digits from a pair
  fr = pair[0]
  to = pair[1]

  # add edges in both directions (undirected)
  d[fr].append(to)
  d[to].append(fr)

# see what we got
print d
```

result

```
{'1': ['2', '8'], '3': ['2', '4'], '2': ['1', '3'], '5': ['4', '6'], '4': ['3', '5'], '7': ['6', '8'], '6': ['5', '7'], '8': ['7', '1']}
```

Comment: Might want to consider sets for values to avoid duplicate paths.

Comment: This would be very helpful. Any advise on how to approach this? Sorry i am relatively new to programming. Thank you @wwii

Comment: Use a set instead of a list for the defaultdict.  Use the (set) add method instead of the (list) append method to add edges/nodes/paths.  Take a look at the Python docs to see further explanation of these types and methods.